# Facebook API - добавить друзей в группу

Tags: json, javascript, facebook-api

Здравствуйте!

Не могу разобраться, как с помощью Facebook Graph API, добавить пользователей в группу, точнее разослать инвайты, так как скорее всего нельзя добавить пользователя без его согласия.

Есть похожая тема на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908688/how-to-add-add-people-to-group-functionality-via-graph-api-or-fql). Но вот что не могу понять, в фейсбуке страница приложения и страница группы это разные вещи. В теме выше обсуждается работа с приложением, а мне надо с группой. Или я все таки напутал что-то? И собственно сам вопрос тогда, как через API разослать ивайты друзьям, чтобы пригласить их в группу?

**UPDATE**
Разобрался с приложениями и группами. В приложение указал группу к которой оно относится, получил app_token, и теперь пытаюсь отправить POST запрос, согласно документации Facebook Graph API:

```
POST /v2.2/{group-id}/members HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

member=1234567
```

Тоесть, используя Graph API Explorer, я ввожу следующий запрос:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/group-id/members/user-id
```

Выбираю метод POST, а также ввожу выше свой app_token. В итоге получаю ошибку:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 102
}
}
```

Вводя access_token, получаю другую ошибку с просьбой ввести app_token

Что делаю не правильно?(